# use of variable in EXPECT_CALL

Tags: c++, c++11, googlemock

I have a simple mock class for a serial interface:

```
class MockSerialPort : public drivers::SerialPort
{
  public:
    MockSerialPort() : SerialPort(){};

    MOCK_METHOD((Result<size_t>), Read, (uint8_t *, size_t, (const duration<int64_t, std::micro> &)), (override));
    MOCK_METHOD((Result<size_t>), Write, (const uint8_t *, size_t), (override));
};
```

During the expected `Read` call I'd like to know what the buffer length that the calling code is expecting so that I can copy the data to the buffer properly. For example:

```
EXPECT_CALL(port_, Read(NotNull(),length,_))
                .WillOnce(DoAll(SetArrayArgument<0>(&data[0], &data[length]), Return(length)));
```

What is the correct syntax to do it? If I specify the variable as above then the value in it is what we *expect*. But how do I not fail the expect call and actually store the value that the caller of `Read` specified?

Comment: When you specify a particular value in an `EXPECT_CALL` argument that is taken as an instruction to match the value exactly. So unless the caller provides that parameter with that same value, the expectation will not match and the actions will not be executed.

Comment: @VladLosev: I really not interested in what the `Read` caller use for size. I would use `_` for that. But it would be nice to know this value so that it could be used in the array arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In such "complicated" cases - use lamdba expression - or some other function, functor object:

```
EXPECT_CALL(port_, Read(NotNull(),_ ,_))
                .WillOnce([](uint8_t *data, size_t length, const duration<int64_t, std::micro> &) {
   // do with data and length whatever you want
   return length;
});
```

This is possible since gtest1.10 - but from the fact that you are using MOCK_METHOD - I see that you are using newest gtest.

In short - replace `DoAll(....)` with some functor object - like lambda expression.